# RevMobAds delegate issue

Tags: ios, ios6, delegates, revmob

I am trying to receive RevMobAdsDelegate events in my AppDelegate and they are not being called. See below what I have done:

1) Implement RevMobAdsDelegate protocol:

```
@interface MyiOSAppAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RevMobAdsDelegate>
```

2) Initializing RevMobAds with ID:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // other code here..
    // Revmob initialization
    [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID: @"SECRET_APP_ID"];
    // other code here..
}
```

3) Calling RevMob Ad:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
}
```

4) Declaring RevMobAdsDelegate events:

```
- (void) revmobAdDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"1");
}

- (void) revmobAdDidReceive
{
    NSLog(@"2");
}

- (void) revmobAdDisplayed
{
    NSLog(@"3");
}

- (void) revmobUserClickedInTheAd
{
    NSLog(@"4");
}

- (void) revmobUserClosedTheAd
{
    NSLog(@"5");
}
```

Ads are appearing fine and there is no problem with that, but none of the above functions are being called. I also tried

[RevMobAds session].delegate = self;

but nothing happened. This last line is not mentioned anywhere in [RevMobAds Documentation](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios.html)
 but I still tried. Can anyone help how I can call these events?

Any help here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delegates are only available with the object ads, check the [API Documentation](http://sdk.revmob.com/api/ios/index.html).

But you can use something like this:

```
RevMobFullscreen *ad = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
ad.delegate = self;
[ad showAd];
```

Or you can use the new block "delegates":

```
 RevMobFullscreen *ad = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
 [ad loadWithSuccessHandler:^(RevMobFullscreen *fs) {
   [fs showAd];
   NSLog(@"Ad loaded");
 } andLoadFailHandler:^(RevMobFullscreen *fs, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"Ad error: %@",error);
 } onClickHandler:^{
   NSLog(@"Ad clicked");
 } onCloseHandler:^{
   NSLog(@"Ad closed");
 }];
```